# ¿Cómo salir de un menú preguntando al usuario con recursividad?

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con un método. Resulta que tengo hecho un menú con switch y dentro de cada case: quero preguntar al usuario si quiere salir del menú. Para esto hago uso de un método recursivo que se llama así mismo si el usuario se ha equivocado:

```
public static bool preguntarVolver()
    {
        string respuesta="";
        bool finalizar = false;

        Console.WriteLine("\n¿Quieres volver al menu? y/n");
        respuesta = Console.ReadLine();

        if (respuesta.Equals("y") || respuesta.Equals("n"))
        {
            if (respuesta.Equals("n"))
            {
                finalizar = true;
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nValor introducido erroneo.");
            preguntarVolver();
        }
        return finalizar;
    }
```

El problema que al teclear a propósito cualquier cadena y luego introduces bien la "n", por algún motivo vuelve a entrar en el método y hace que devuelva false.

Actualizo con lo nuevo que hice y ya funciona.

```
public static bool PreguntarVolver()
    {
        string respuesta;
        bool error = true;
        bool finalizar=false;

        while (error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n¿Quieres volver al menu? y/n");
            respuesta = Console.ReadLine();

            if (respuesta.Equals("y") || respuesta.Equals("n"))
            {
                if (respuesta.Equals("n"))
                {
                    finalizar = true;
                }
                error = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nValor introducido erroneo.");
            }
        }
        return finalizar;
    }
```

Gracias por ayudar.

Comment: Pon un switch con las opciones de "n" y "y" y en el default haces la recursividad, siento que te queda mas fácil. Puedes ir revisando que valor tiene tu variable cuando se va ejecutando colocando un breakpoint

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La recursividad no es para esto. La recursividad tiene que tener un fin tangible, y una entrada de usuario no lo es. Esto es mucho mas simple con un bucle while.... NO uses recursividad para esto...

Comment: Lo hice y al depurar el código entiendo que valor tiene cada variable en cada momento, pero no entiendo porque no sale del método recursivo cuando según las variables debería de dejar.

Comment: @Asklat Podrías cambiar eso y en lugar de hacer un método recursivo, simplemente hacer un DO WHILE con la petición de la información y que se repita mientras los valores ingresados no sean validos. Una vez obtenido eso, debajo del do while colocas return respuesta.Equals("y") (ya que el if preguntando para asignar en finalizar esta de mas)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement

Comment: Si tuviste problemas con el Do while, comparte lo que tenes.

Comment: @Orion funciona perfectamente con while.

Comment: @Asklat Genial!